# for vs while - LOOP

Tags: java, loops

Tengo estas pequeñas dudas sobre `loops` en `java`.

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `for` y `while`?
- ¿Es mejor el `while` para un bucle corto?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Estructura de Iteración**

Una estructura de iteración es una estructura que agrupa sentencias de código, dichas sentencias se ejecutan una y otra vez hasta  que *x* condición se torne falsa.

### 1. `while`

### 1.1 Sintaxis

```
while(condicion){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

### 1.2 Descripción

La estructura de control while, recibe un parámetro llamado `condicion` que se evaluará al iniciar cada iteración. `condicion` es un valor *booleano*, esto significa que sólo puede contener dos valores `true` o `false` . Si en algún momento `condicion` se torna `false` el bucle ( `loop` ) terminará.

> El bucle termina en la primera ocasión en que `condicion` se torne `false`.

### 1.3 Ejemplo #1

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 11) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

En el bucle anterior, la condicion es `i < 11` , inicialmente `i = 0` por lo que al evaluarla en la condicion `i < 11` éste contiene el valor `true` por lo tanto la esctructura prosigue a ejecutar las sentencias contenidas en él, Al ejecutar `i++` en la primera iteración el valor de `i` cambia, ahora `i = 1`, la esctrucutra repite el anterior proceso para éste nuevo valor, se evalua `i` dentro de la expresión , si `i` contiene `true` entonces se procede a ejecutar `i++`.

- P : ¿Hasta cuando termina el bucle?
- R : Hasta que `i >= 11` , esto quiere decir que el bucle termina cuando `i = 11` puesto que `i`
  incrementa a un paso de `1`, `i++` se ejecutó un total de `11` veces.

Salida del programa :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

### 2. `for`

### 2.1 Sintaxis

```
for(variables ; condicion ; instrucciones){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

### 2.2 Descripción

La estructura de control for, contrario a while, se segmenta en 3 partes, `variables` es un espacio designado para la declaración de variables locales que serán accesibles sólo dentro de la estructura. `condicion` se interpreta igual que en la estructura `while`, finalmente `instrucciones` es un espacio designado para colocar sentencias que se ejecutarán despues de una iteración

> El bucle termina en la primera ocasión en que `condicion` se torne `false`.

### 2.3 Ejemplo #2

```
for(int i = 0, j = 10 ; i < 11 ; i++ , j--){
    System.out.println(i + "," + j);
}
```

En el anterior ejemplo, se crean dos variables locales `i` y `j`, ambas del tipo `int`, con valores iniciales `i = 0` , `j = 10` , la condición es la misma que el ejemplo #1 . Después de ejecutar la sentencia `System.out.println(i + "," + j);` se ejecutarán adicionalmente las sentencias `i++` y `j--` que incrementan el valor de `i` y decrementan el valor de `j` respectivamente.

Salida del programa :

```
0,10
1,9
2,8
3,7
4,6
5,5
6,4
7,3
8,2
9,1
10,0
```

---

### 3. Conversión entre estructuras de iteración

### 3.1 `for` a `while`

Esta conversión sin duda alguna es la más simple de todas (straightforward)

```
for(variables ; condicion ; instrucciones){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

Es equivalente a

```
variables;
while(condicion){
    ... // sentencias
    instrucciones;
}
```

La explicación es sencilla, se declararan las variables antes, la expresión a evaluar es la misma, finalmente a las sentencias se les agrega las sentencias post-iteración al final de la estructura.

Ejemplo : Conversión del ejemplo #2

> `for(int i = 0, j = 10 ; i < 11 ; i++ , j--){
>          System.out.println(i + "," + j);
>      }`

```
int i =  0,
    j = 10;
while(i < 11){
    System.out.println(i + "," + j);
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

### 3.2 `while` a `for`

Contrario a la conversión de `for - while`, la conversión `while - for` no es tan obvia, puesto que la transformación

```
while(condicion){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

En

```
for(; condicion ;){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

No es muy útil y resulta en pérdidas semánticas. Pero no todo es malo, por suerte, anteriormente se descubrió que

```
variables;
while(condicion){
    ... // sentencias
    instrucciones;
}
```

Es equivalente a

```
for(variables ; condicion ; instrucciones){
    ... // sentencias
}
```

si se tiene un `while` de la forma descrita anteriormente, la conversión a `for` es sencilla. se localiza primero las variables usadas dentro del while, luego las transformaciones finales a esas mismas variables.

Ejemplo : Conversión del ejemplo # 1

> `int i = 0;
>   while(i < 11) {
>       System.out.println(i);
>       i++;
>   }`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11 ; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

---

### Respondiendo

> ¿Es mejor el while para un bucle corto?

Dependerá mayormente de la estructura del `while`, recordando que `while` y `for` son totalmente equivalentes, la elección de una no afectará la funcionalidad del código, no obstante la elección de una sobre otra, hará el código más legible, es decir más fácil de leer.

Por ejemplo el `while` del ejemplo # 1 , el equivalente en `for` resultó en un mejor código.

No obstante el siguiente `while`

```
while(buffer.nextChar()!= EOF){
    ...         
}
```

Su equivalente en `for` empeora la legibilidad del código

```
for(;buffer.nextChar()!= EOF;){
    ...
}
```

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre switch, for y while?

`for` y `while` son estructuras de iteración.

`switch` es una estructura de selección, muy similar a varios `if`'s anidados , no entraré en detalles puesto que ya fue respondida por [Quidi90](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27226/quidi90)

Comment: **recordando que while y for son totalmente equivalentes,** eso no es cierto!!!

Comment: Son totalmente equivalentes, Todo `for` se puede transformar en `while` y todo `while` en `for` por ende son equivalentes, si quieres la demostración basta definir una función auxiliar booleana con tabla de pertenencia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Equivalence_with_while-loops

Comment: no son equivalentes en tiempo de ejecucion, lo que mencionas se va mas a la sintaxis, claro que se convierten

Comment: ademas que el indice de for no puede ser modificado en el cuerpo del for, en cambio la variable que depende while si se modifica, ve mi respuesta

Comment: Bueno, esto es toda una documentación, excelente aportación, gracias!

Answer (score 8):

El `While` se suele llamar "bucle de condición", es decir, el programador no sabe cuantas veces se va a ejecutar el bucle y este simplemente continuará cuando acabe la condición impuesta en el bucle.

Por otro lado el `For` se trata de un bucle de control con el que el desarrollador repite el bucle un determinado número de veces en el que el desarrollador sabe cuantas o al menos aproximadamente cuantas veces se va a ejecutar.

Comment: ¿Y en qué mejora tu respuesta a la de @x-rw publicada hace ya mas de un mes?

Comment: Simplemente quería ofrecer un coimentario más breve y concreto. Disculpa

Comment: @F3rran no te disculpes, ese usuario es agresivo con los usarios nuevos y no sabe comunicarse bien. Igual x aqui sabemos que quiere lo mejor (?). Por otro lado a mi me parece informacion bastante util. No dejes de participar y Suerte!

Comment: @EmanuelVe  O sea que como estás en desacuerdo vienes aquí a dar otro voto más a una respuesta que no aporta nada y sin embargo la de x-rw que respondió más completo hace un mes no se lleva nada... Es un claro ejemplo del fallo que tiene el sistema del sufragio universal.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n En ningún momento hemos desprestigiado la otra respuesta que por supuesto es más completa. Simplemente quise dar una versión más breve para todo aquel que prefiere respuestas más cortas.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n no aporta nada segun tu opinion.

Comment: @F3rran En realidad tu respuesta no es "mas corta". En realidad tu respuesta es redundante y por tanto hace la publicación "más larga". Si no existiera la gente ahorraría en su vida los segundos que tarda en leerla y no ganaría nada pues ya lo pone todo en las otras. No te lo tomes a lo personal ni creas que soy agresivo como te dicen. Digo lo que veo e intento argumentártelo lo mejor que se me ocurre. No es mi intención ofender. Tampoco pido disculpas, solo creo que sería mejor eliminarla y por supuesto que no reciba más votos que otra mejor.

Comment: @EmanuelVe lo único que aporta es un recuento de votos injusto para un miembro que respondió esto y mas hace más de un mes. Una respuesta tardía sin añadir nada a una pregunta que incluso ya tiene una respuesta aceptada me parece añadir contenido innecesariamente al sitio. Te invito a compartir con el resto el valor añadido de esta respuesta que yo no soy capaz de apreciar.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n si fuera tu, buscaria un mejor ejemplo porque esa respuesta que mencionas es bastante mala. Y por cierto, yo no comparo las respuestas, las miro de forma unica. Tengo una idea diferente que tu acerca de como funciona el sitio. Si tienes dudas chat o meta. fuera.

Answer (score 0):

Empiezo explicando el switch. A diferencia de los otros 2 no realiza ningún tipo de bucle es más bien como una sucesión de if.

```
switch(day) {
   case 'lunes':
     contador++;
     break;
   case 'martes':
     contador += 2;
   case 'miercoles':
     contador += 3;
     break;
   case 'default':
     contador = 2;
     break;
}
```

En este caso utilizamos la variable day para realizar el switch. Si su valor es 'lunes' se le sumará uno a la variable contador. Si es 'miercoles' se le sumará 3. En cambio si es 'martes se le sumará 5, debido a que no existe la instrucción break y una vez que entras en el switch lo recorres hasta el final a no ser que te encuentres un break. Por otro lado en caso de que no valga ninguno de los otros valores existe el caso default (que no es obligatorio), sería como el else del switch.

Por el otro lado while y for sirven para realizar bucles. La diferencia radica en que for está especializado (optimizado) para realizar bucles del tipo necesito un índice, que se cumple una condición y hacer algo con ese índice. Por lo tanto siempre que se cumple la estructura de un for (sin importar el tamaño a recorrer) se debería usar el for.

Comment: La primera parte, acaerca de switch, está fuera de tema.

Comment: Antes de que editara la pregunta había puesto: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre switch, for y while? Así que no creo que esté fuera de lugar.

Answer (score -2):

**Cuando usar `FOR`?**

`for` se utiliza cuando se sabe el final de la iteracion 
ejemplo:

```
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
***notese que `i` no puede ser  modificado, si se modifica ocasionara errores de ejecucion***

    }
```

> analizando en codigo de arriba,
>
> i inicia en 0
>
> i recorrera hasta 100(sabemos donde terminara el bucle)

**Cuando usar WHILE?**

while se utiliza cuando no se sabe cuando terminada la iteracion 
ejemplo:

```
while(n%2==0){



n=((n*100)/3)+5;
}
```

***notese que `n` esta siendo modificado***, esto es clave para entender y diferenciar cuando usar `for` o `while`

analizando elcodigo de arriba:

> El bucle de while depende de la variable `n`.--> `while(n%2==0){`
>
> la variable `n` va cambiando de valor --> `n=n/10;` por ese motivo no
>   se sabe cuando acabara, **y eso dependera del valor de n**.
>
> por lo tanto los cálculos se podrian hacer exponencial.

**Cuando usar Swith?**

swith se utiliza para emparejar el valor de una variable con casos y ademas que los casos tienen que ser finitos:

ejemplo:
los meses del anio

```
switch(mes) {
   case 'enero':
     //hacer algo
     break;
   case 'febrero':
     //hacer algo
     break;
   case 'marzo':
     //hacer algo
     break;
   .
   .
   .
   //etc hasta diciembre
}
```

**¿Es mejor el while para un bucle corto?**

NO, se supone que un bucle es corto cuando se sabe el final de **hecho**, por lo tanto lo conveniente es usar `for`

***informacion Extra:***

El tiempo de ejecución de `for`(for simple, no anidado) es **n**
el tiempo de ejecucion de while es mayor a "n" ya que se trata de iteraciones exponenciales

conclucion: no es lo mismo usar for y while en cualquier caso, por que seria matar a una mosca con una bomba :)

Comment: Totalmente falso, contradices la teoría de análisis de algoritmos, un `for` no tiene un "tiempo de ejecución" igual 1,en base a qué afirmas en que while se trata de iteraciones exponenciales. Basta llevar tu código a ensamblador, y verás que no hay ninguna diferencia entre un while y un for... al final de todo es un simple salto condicional.

Comment: La única diferencia es la alocación de las variables, puesto que el `for`, crea un nuevo scope con su respectiva tabla de símbolos, esos detalles a bajo nivel consumen un factor k ciclos, despreciables en un lenguaje de alto de nivel.

Comment: Un contra ejemplo de que `for` no es es de complejidad asintótica 1, basta con el algoritmo de búsqueda secuencial, el cuál tiene una complejidad asintótica Omega(n) , no Omega(1) mucho menos O(1) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search, y ahí una contradicción a tu afirmación.

Comment: En general la complejidad asintótica, o bien la cuota superior asintótica  (ambas distintas), dependen unicamente de la `condicion` nunca de la estructura de iteración. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms

Comment: Si gustas proseguir con el debate http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52254/analisis-de-algoritmos, ya no comentaré en este hito para evitar confundir a espectadores, si pasa un moderador y considera útil borrar comentarios, hacedlo.

Comment: @EduenSarceño entonces for y while son iguales?

Comment: hasta ahora leo esto y sí, son totalmente iguales a grandes rasgos