# Substrings en c++

Tags: c++

veréis, tengo que hacer un examen en pseudocódigo mañana y ahora me estoy liando un poco con el tema de strings... Repasando estaba haciendo un ejercicio que pedía que hiciésemos un programa que dijera si el primer string era substring del segundo, es decir, si aparece o no. El caso es que yo sé hacerlo con un for y cuando se cumpla "X" condición, le meto un break, y apañados. Pero el profe dice que si hay un break en un for, ese for es posiblemente un while, y es lo que he intentado hacer, pero no consigo, este es el útlimo código que he probado.

```
int main()
{

    string cadena1, cadena2;
    int comptador = 0, longitudCadena = 0, longitudCadena2, pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0;
    bool substr = false;


    cout << "Entra la cadena" << endl;
    getline(cin, cadena1);
    cout << "Entra la cadena 2" << endl;
    getline(cin, cadena2);

    longitudCadena = cadena1.length() - 1;
    longitudCadena2 = cadena2.length() - 1;


    while (pos2 < cadena2.length()){

        if (cadena1[pos1] == cadena2[pos2]){
            pos1++;
        }else{
            pos1 = 0;
        }

        if (pos1 == longitudCadena){
            substr = true;
        }else{
            substr = false;
        }

        pos2++;

    }


    if (substr == true){
        cout << "Es substring" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "No es substring" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` y `while` poseen dos diferencias básicas:

- `for` permite la inicialización de variables en la declaración
- `for` dispone de un sitio especial para realizar los incrementos entre iteración

Debido a estas dos diferencias, elegir entre `for` y `while` no debería medirse en si el bucle va a tener un `break` sino en las particularidades de cada bucle. Un ejemplo para buscar un elemento en una lista:

```
// condiciones iniciales
int numeros[100];
int indice = -1;

// for v1
for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
{
  if( numeros[i] == 25 )
  {
    indice = i;
    break;
  }
}

// for v2
for( int i=0; i<100 && indice == -1; i++ )
{
  if( numeros[i] == 25 )
    indice = i;
}

// while
int i = 0;
while( indice != -1 )
{
  if( numeros[i] == 25 )
    indice = i;
  else
    i++;
}
```

No se tu, pero yo prefiero, en este caso, una de las dos primeras opciones aunque sea solo por claridad.

Desde mi punto de vista, `for` debería utilizarse para iterar sobre rangos cuyos límites son conocidos y dejar `while` para aquellos casos en los que el rango de iteración es más bien difuso...

Dicho esto, tu algoritmo para localizar un substring en una cadena es incorrecto:

```
while (pos2 < cadena2.length()){

    if (cadena1[pos1] == cadena2[pos2]){
        pos1++;
    }else{
        pos1 = 0;
    }

    if (pos1 == longitudCadena){
        substr = true;
    }else{
        substr = false;
    }

    pos2++;
}
```

La búsqueda debería comprender dos bucles y tu únicamente tienes uno. Deberías verificar el substring por cada carácter de la cadena principal, lo que implica un bucle para iterar sobre la cadena principal y otro para saber si el substring se encuentra a partir de esa posición.

```
for( int i=0; cadena1[i] != 0; i++ )
{
  for( int pos1 = i, pos2 = 0; ;pos1++, pos2++  )
  {
    if( cadena2[pos2] == 0 )
    {
      substr = true;
      break;
    }
    if( cadena1[pos1] != cadena2[pos2] )
      break;
  }

  if( substr )
    break;
}
```

O si lo prefieres sin `break`:

```
for( int i=0; cadena1[i] != 0 && !substr; i++ )
{
  for( int pos1 = i, pos2 = 0;                       // inicializadores
       !substr && cadena1[pos1] == cadena2[pos2];    // comparaciones
       pos1++, pos2++, substr = (cadena2[pos2] == 0))// incrementos
  { }
}
```

Y si lo prefieres con un `while`:

```
for( int i=0; cadena1[i] != 0 && !substr; i++ )
{
  int pos1 = i, pos2 = 0;
  while( !substr )
  {
    if( cadena1[pos1] != cadena2[pos2] )
      break;

    pos1++, pos2++;
    substr = (cadena2[pos2] == 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: en este tema http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45355/for-vs-while-loop afirma que `for` y `while` son totalmente iguales, por lo tanto estaria metiendo confusion a los lectores.

Comment: @x-rw ¿Piensas que las diferencias que comento no son tales? Yo no veo que `while` tenga un apartado destinado a realizar los incrementos entre iteraciones... ni tampoco un apartado destinado a la inicialización de variables. `while` es una versión primitiva de `for`... es más versátil y exige más cuidado a la hora de programarlo.

Comment: @x-rw por cierto... esa pregunta es aplicable a Java, no a C++. Que Java y C++ se parezcan en algún aspecto de la sintaxis no implica necesariamente que funcionen igual

Comment: lo que digo es que tu respuesta es totalmente verdadera, citando **Desde mi punto de vista, for debería utilizarse para iterar sobre rangos cuyos límites son conocidos y dejar while para aquellos casos en los que el rango de iteración es más bien difuso...**

Comment: @x-rw ahora ya si estamos hablando el mismo idioma. Lo que pretendo transmitir es que no hay reglas fijas sobre qué tipo de bucle es mejor para cada situación... eso es algo que depende del propio escenario y que lo único que se pueden dictar son normas generales.

Comment: en la respuesta aceptada del tema que deje dice que while y for son totalmente iguales y no importa cuando usar for o while, y que se puede convertir un for en while, pero como tu mismo dices eso depende del contexto y no asi de la sintaxis, claro que se puede convertir pero no se debe usar while o for adecuados a la situacion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52874/discussion-between-eferion-and-x-rw).